# My JS script only highlights the option doesn't change it to the one I want in the box

Tags: javascript, html

So my script doesn't change the the option in the drop-menu to the one I want it to be.
Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kerandom12/yzn3h96L/22/

```
function add(){
  var array = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    var item = array[i].innerHTML;
    if (item == 6.5) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].selectedIndex = i;
      return item;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the code and click on the drop menu it only shows a 6.5 highlighted instead of being chosen and changed to that value.
Any Idea why?

NEW FIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/kerandom12/yzn3h96L/57/

Comment: Not sure to understand, you script select the second item (by index) which is 6.5 in the drop menu. What is wrong?

Comment: It highlights it but when i click the submit button 6 shows up. Not shown in the Fiddle. Sorry for the lack of clarification.

Comment: Your select is hidden so I changed opacity `style="opacity: 1;"`. Then on click on `click me` the select change to 6.5 but this span `<span style="-moz-user-select: none;">6</span>`does not.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what is controlling what is getting added. When I click the submit on the website I get a 6 instead of a 6.5. Do you think a function is being called?

Comment: I can't answer in case of your submit, it is better you illustrate with code.

Comment: When I select the drop menu manually, the span element you note change as well could that be it?

Comment: I updated the Fiddle. So basically when I run the script and then click add instead of showing up a 6.5 it shows a 6

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery when you're not actually using it?